# How to Handle and get response from goroutines in golang

Tags: go, grpc, server-sent-events, goroutine

I have go routines called in getPosition, getStatus and rerouting for my drone currently I am invoking go GetStatus in my main function which this function has go func() which handles the event for streaming grpc and sse.

currently this is my code and i tried

```
func GetPositionContext(ctx context.Context, uav pb.UAVControllerClient, uavID *pb.UAVID, projectID string) {
    log.Printf("getPosition start")

    stream, err := uav.GetPosition(ctx)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("ERROR getPosition:%s", err.Error())
    }

    streamID, eventName := EventsSubscribe(projectID, uavID.Aircraft, "get_position")

    position := make(chan models.DronePosition)

    // 受信ループ開始
    go func() {
        fmt.Print("start getPosition loop")
        for {
            msg, err := stream.Recv() // msg UAVPosition
            if err == io.EOF {
                // read done.
                fmt.Print("start getPosition loop closed")
                close(position)
                return
            }
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Failed to receive getPosition : %v", err)
                close(position)
                return
            }
            // log.Printf("Position point[%s](%f, %f, %f) H:%f", uavID.Aircraft, msg.Latitude, msg.Longitude, msg.Altitude, msg.Heading)

            wayPoint := models.WaypointItem{
                Latitude:  msg.Latitude,
                Longitude: msg.Longitude,
                Altitude:  msg.Altitude,
                Heading:   msg.Heading,
            }

            dronePosition := models.DronePosition{
                Name:          uavID.Aircraft,
                ItemParameter: wayPoint,
            }

            // publish to eventgo
            publishNotif(dronePosition, streamID, eventName)
            return
        }
    }()

    startMsg := pb.UAVControllerPositionRequest{
        UavID:       uavID,
        Instruction: true,
        Interval:    2,
    }

    fmt.Print("send getPosition start")

    if err := stream.Send(&startMsg); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to send getPosition: %v", err)
    }

    <-position

    stream.CloseSend()
    fmt.Print("end of getPosition")
}
```

this is the part where i call this function

```
go utils.GetPosition(ctx, uavService, &uavID, projectID)
```

I want to get the return values from go func like if everything works fine in the grpc server and no problem i should return 200 success and 500 if something failed.

```
for {
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(60) * time.Second)
    }
```

after the call i have this code which it should return every 10s a success

```
return c.JSON(500, failed or pass)
```

I expect something to return to the ui if go routines is success or failed when streaming part is working for the response not to be pending or else other api call will not work.

Comment: please if you have any idea help please

Comment: You simply _cannot_ get a "response from a goroutine": This simply is not possible. If you want to communicate any result from a goroutine to an other goroutine you normally use a channel. (You should come up with a simplified example as I have no idea what your code does or is intended to do).

Comment: currently yes am calling another go routines to pass the value ```func F(n int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
 // defer wg.Done()
 defer wg.Done()
 // do a job here
 Results <- n
}
```
and a variable like a channel var Results = make(chan int)
```

Comment: this is the code https://play.golang.org/p/NioLLk1NVds

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if there was an error when processing the go func() inside GetPositionContext then you could do something like below. I modified all errors to bubble up rather than call log.Fatal. On a side note it might be wise to defer `stream.CloseSend()`, but i'm missing context and it's outside the scope of the question.

I did my best to understand the question, but if I missed something, let me know!

The code has been modified to bubble up errors within GetPositionContext directly rather than call log.Fatal. Additionally, if there is an error within the go func() it will get sent back to GetPositionContext through a channel and then returned to the caller.

```
func GetPositionContext(ctx context.Context, uav pb.UAVControllerClient, uavID *pb.UAVID, projectID string) error {
    log.Printf("getPosition start")

    stream, err := uav.GetPosition(ctx)

    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("ERROR getPosition: %v", err.Error())
    }

    streamID, eventName := EventsSubscribe(projectID, uavID.Aircraft, "get_position")

    errC := make(chan error)

    // 受信ループ開始
    go func() {
        fmt.Print("start getPosition loop")
        for {
            msg, err := stream.Recv() // msg UAVPosition
            if err == io.EOF {
                // read done.
                fmt.Print("start getPosition loop closed")
                close(errC)
                return
            }
            if err != nil {
                errC <- fmt.Errorf("Failed to receive getPosition : %v", err)
                return
            }
            // log.Printf("Position point[%s](%f, %f, %f) H:%f", uavID.Aircraft, msg.Latitude, msg.Longitude, msg.Altitude, msg.Heading)

            wayPoint := models.WaypointItem{
                Latitude:  msg.Latitude,
                Longitude: msg.Longitude,
                Altitude:  msg.Altitude,
                Heading:   msg.Heading,
            }

            dronePosition := models.DronePosition{
                Name:          uavID.Aircraft,
                ItemParameter: wayPoint,
            }

            // publish to eventgo
            publishNotif(dronePosition, streamID, eventName)

            // Did you mean to return here? The for loop will only ever execute one time.
            // If you didn't mean to return, then remove this close
            close(errC)
            return
        }
    }()

    startMsg := pb.UAVControllerPositionRequest{
        UavID:       uavID,
        Instruction: true,
        Interval:    2,
    }

    fmt.Print("send getPosition start")

    if err := stream.Send(&startMsg); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Failed to send getPosition: %v", err)
    }

    err = <- errC

    stream.CloseSend()
    fmt.Print("end of getPosition")
    return err
}
```

If you want to call this function asynchronously, but still want to know if there was an error then you could do the following.

```
errC := make(chan error)
go func() {
  errC <- GetPositionContext(..........)
}()
// Do some other stuff here
// Until you need the result
err := <- errC


// ... and Eventually when you want to return the success or failure as JSON
if err != nil {
  return c.JSON(500, failed)
}
return c.JSON(500, pass)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
i will check and let you know it seems good.

Comment: but eventhough the result is return is there any possible that this will continue running except removing close(errC)? this is the stream from grpc so i dont want to stop the streaming

Comment: The for loop in go func() will continue looping until it hits a return. At any point you want to end the loop (return), be sure to send an error into the channel or close the channel.

Comment: ah ok thats fine as well, but my goal currently is when the streaming is working fine it should return something like 200 or else 500 if err != nil then thats the time i send the error. I am modifying it now but cannot get a good result.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting up a channel to receive events from the go routine. In the calling function you can listen for these events (which can contain any information you want) in a loop until the go routine closes itself, signigying failure.